# Handle null values of nested objects in C# expression tree

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have searched, and found similar posts pertaining to my issue, however nothing seems to solve my problem.

I am fairly new to C#, and this is my first attempt at building an expression tree. (please go easy ;-)

I am trying to create an expression tree which would, once compiled, filter values on a set of data.

Here is my expression method:

```
private static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> CreateFilterExpression<TItem>(string propertyName, string expressionType, dynamic filterValue)
{
    if (param == null)
    {
        param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem), "item");
    }
    MemberExpression member = GetMemberExpression<TItem>(propertyName);

    //When we call our method, we need to evaluate on the same type
    //we convert the filter value to the type of the property we are evaluating on
    dynamic convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(filterValue, member.Type);
    MethodInfo method = member.Type.GetMethod(expressionType, new[] { member.Type });
    ConstantExpression constantValue = Expression.Constant(convertedValue, member.Type);
    Expression containsMethodExp;

    if (expressionType == "NotEqual")
    {
        method = member.Type.GetMethod("Equals", new[] { member.Type });
    }
    if (member.Type.ToString().ToLower() == "system.string")
    {
        //We need to compare the lower case of property and value
        MethodCallExpression propertyValueToLowerCase = Expression.Call(member, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
        MethodCallExpression filterValueToLowerCase = Expression.Call(constantValue, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
        containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyValueToLowerCase, method, filterValueToLowerCase);
    }
    else if (member.Type.ToString().ToLower() == "system.datetime")
    {
        //we need to compare only the dates
        MemberExpression dateOnlyProperty = Expression.Property(member, "Date");
        containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(dateOnlyProperty, method, constantValue);
    }
    else
    {
        containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(member, method, constantValue);
    }

    if (expressionType == "NotEqual")
    {
        containsMethodExp = Expression.Not(containsMethodExp);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(containsMethodExp, param);
}

private static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<TItem>(string propertyName)
{
    if (param == null)
    {
        param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem), "item");
    }
    MemberExpression member = null;

    //Check if we have a nested property
    if (propertyName.Contains('.'))
    {
        Expression nestedProperty = param;
        string[] properies = propertyName.Split('.');
        int zeroIndex = properies.Count() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= zeroIndex; i++)
        {
            if (i < zeroIndex)
            {
                nestedProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(nestedProperty, properies[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                member = Expression.Property(nestedProperty, properies[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        member = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
    }
    return member;
}
```

Example usage would be like so:

```
var lambda = CreateFilterExpression<T>("Some.Nested.Object", "Equals", "Some value");
var compiled = lambda.Compile();
gridData = gridData.Where(compiled);
```

An example of the data I trying to ultimately bind to my grid looks like this:

```
public class Some : BaseClass
{
    public decimal NumberAvailable { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public Batch Batch { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Limit { get; set; }
    public NestedClass Nested { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class NestedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
}
```

The problem occurs when we have null value on an object, like "Some.Nested = null", and then trying to convert "Reference" to lowercase. Here:

```
MethodCallExpression propertyValueToLowerCase = Expression.Call(member, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
```

Here is the result in debugger:

[image]

How can I check for null values, on nested objects, and return empty string if it is null?

I hope I explained my question well enough. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can add if statement in expression and check that curret property not null before trying get property

Comment: Thanks Grundy, maybe I misunderstood, but this would need to be dynamic, for any amount of nested objects?

Comment: can you provide `GetMemberExpression`?

Comment: Sure, have edited my question and added GetMemberExpression method

Comment: There are a number of references to param - which isn't declared anywhere.  Just a static private member?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is to generate an expression like this:

```
Some == null ? null : Some.Nested == null ? null : Some.Nested.Object
```

This unfortunately is no longer a member expression, so `GetMemberExpression` wouldn’t work for this. Instead you need a chain of conditional expression that accesses one more level at a time.

Once you have that, you could then do `<memberExpression> ?? string.Empty` to get a string which you can safely operate on.

To generate the latter expression, you can use [`Expression.Coalesce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302730.aspx):

```
Expression.Coalesce(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(string.Empty))
```

For the member expression itself, you could write something like this:

```
Expression AccessMember(Expression obj, string propertyName)
{
    string[] parts = propertyName.Split(new char[] { '.' }, 2);
    Expression member = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, parts[0]);

    if (parts.Length > 1)
        member = AccessMember(member, parts[1]);

    return Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(obj, Expression.Constant(null)),
        Expression.Constant(null, member.Type), member);
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
string path = "Some.Nested.Object";
string[] parts = path.Split(new char[] { '.' }, 2);
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), parts[0]);
Expression memberAccess = AccessMember(param, parts[1]);
```

`memberAccess` would then be exactly the above chained conditional expression.

Combined into your function (simplified only for strings for now), it could look like this:

```
Expression<Func<TObj, bool>> BuildFilterExpression<TObj, TMember>(string propertyPath, TMember comparisonValue, TMember defaultValue)
{
    string[] parts = propertyPath.Split(new char[] { '.' }, 2);
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObj), parts[0]);

    // get member access expression
    Expression memberExpression = AccessMember(param, parts[1]);

    // coalesce the member with the default value
    memberExpression = Expression.Coalesce(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(defaultValue));

    // get the comparison value as expression
    Expression comparisonExpression = Expression.Constant(comparisonValue);

    // type specific logic
    if (memberExpression.Type == typeof(string))
    {
        MethodInfo toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
        memberExpression = Expression.Call(memberExpression, toLowerMethod);
        comparisonExpression = Expression.Call(comparisonExpression, toLowerMethod);
    }

    // create the comparison expression
    Expression filterExpression = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, comparisonExpression);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TObj, bool>>(filterExpression, param);
}
```

Used like this:

```
BuildFilterExpression<SomeType, string>("Some.Nested.Object", "foo bar", string.Empty)
```

… it essentially creates the following lambda expression:

```
(Some) => ((Some == null ? null : Some.Nested == null ? null : Some.Nested.Object) ?? string.Empty).ToLower() == "foo bar"
```

---

Above code assumes that for a property expression `Some.Nested.Object`, `Some` is the object that is being passed to the lambda, so the first property that would be accessed is `Nested`. The reason is that I simply didn’t know your example object structure, so I had to come up with something.

If you want `Some` be the first property that is accessed for the passed object, you can easily change that though. To do that, modify the beginning of `BuildFilterExpression` so that the `propertyPath` is not split up. Pass some random name (or no name even) to `Expression.Parameter`, and pass the full `propertyPath` to `AccessMember`:

```
// don’t split up the propertyPath

// let’s call the parameter `obj`
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObj), "obj");

// get member access expression—for the full property path
Expression memberExpression = AccessMember(param, propertyPath);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Poke! I am busy testing your solution, however I am receiving  an error in the AccessMember method (Expression member = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, parts[0]);).   **"'Nested' is not a member of type 'MyClassName'"** While **Nested** is the null property on the instance of **Some** class.

Comment: Yeah, I didn’t exactly know how your object structure was set up, so in my example, I used `Some` as the object being passed to the lambda, not as the first property that is accessed. So a quick fix would be to do add some prefix in front of the property path, e.g. `obj.Some.Nested.Object`. But I’ll adjust my answer to include how to change this behavior.

Comment: For sure, you had no way of knowing. I have implemented the changes, however I still receive **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**  My constructed expression (thanks for your help) now looks like this: **obj => ((IIF((obj == null), null, IIF((obj.Request == null), null, obj.Request.Reference)) ?? default(String)).ToLower() == "filtervalue".ToLower())** Which looks right, as far as I can see?

Comment: Could you maybe add some small example of your data to the question, so that I can test this properly?

Comment: No problem, I have added a simplified version of the classes I am trying to bind. So the error occurs when my nested class **"NestedClass"** is null on my object. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Of course this was failing. I was using `default(string)` as the fallback when the property is null… but `string` is a reference type itself so the default value is null too… :P I added another parameter to the function, so you can pass `string.Empty` there which is then used as the default. Then everything should work.

Comment: You are an absolute legend! Thanks a lot Poke!